# Receiving Gravity Form Errors within WooCommerce Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two issues which are appearing within my Chrome browsers console.

FYI, I am using WordPress 3.9, Gravity Forms 1.8.8 and WooCommerce Gravity Add On (latest).

Basically, when I am going into one of my products on my site (sorry, only have it running local on my machine), I am receiving the following two errors:

**Error 1**: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gform is not defined`

**Error 2**: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gformCalculateTotalPrice is not defined`

FYI, I am using the `WooCommerce` Gravity Forms Add On but am not using any pricing fields at all within my Gravity forms.

I am not sure how to track down why these errors are occurring or how to prevent them from occurring.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue? Because I'm getting the exact same error when using the `[product_page]` WooCommerce shortcode to show a product on the homepage

Comment: Same problem here "gform is not defined" from Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons plugin (WooCommerce extension) template gravityforms-product-addons-form.php ~line 183. As a workaround until bug is fixed by plugin developer, I added this simple javascript variable check to see if undefined:
`code`
if (typeof gform !== 'undefined'){
 gform.addFilter('gform_product_total', function(total, formId) {
  return update_dynamic_price(total);
 });
}
`code`

Comment: Marty, did you add this code directly on the 'template gravityforms-product-addons-form.php ~line 183'?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `jquery` at header section.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I faced same issue with `Gravity Forms` and `WooCommerce` after initialize `jquery` at header section its resolved for me.

So, i think you have to initialize `jquery` at header section.